# JVMTI profiling: calculating the amount of stack memory

Tags: java, memory-management, stack, jvmti

I am working on a JVMTI agent that monitors memory usage of an application. I have managed to monitor memory allocations on the heap using bytecode instrumentation so that a native method gets invoked whenever a new object/array gets allocated.
But I am really confused about how to determine the amount of memory allocated on the stack.
If you could provide any ideas, tips or links I would greatly appreciate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How much detail are you hoping to get from the JVMTI interface?  It looks like it only reports [logical Java stack frame information](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jvmti/jvmti.html#GetAllStackTraces) which means you can't find out how much actual runtime stack space is being used, but you can use the `jmethodID` to figure out [the layout of a Java Stack Frame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6) to make a reasonable guess (the number of local variables is fixed for a specific method at compile time, see [GetLocalVariableTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jvmti/jvmti.html#GetLocalVariableTable)).  Stack frames for native methods won't be visible.  And other JVM state stored on the stack (e.g., debugging information or space used by the JIT, and thread infrastructure) won't be visible either.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I figured this would be the only way, but was hoping there was a better one I did not see. Guess this will have to do.